# rails autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete

Is there any rails autocomplete plugin other then rails3-jquery-autocomplete plugin? I'm using rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this railscasts episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields